# Create JSON body dynamically and call API in React JS

Tags: json, reactjs, api, state, setstate

I need to show list of questions on screen using React JS. I'll get the list of questions from another system.
When I call the API first time, It returns the first question. When I select the answer for 1st question, I need to call PUT API and in response both 1st and 2nd questions will come. When I select the answer for 2nd question, I need to call same PUT API again and in response 1,2, and 3 questions will come.

the request structure of PUT API something like this -

```
https://json.com/web/api/v/ASSIGNMENT/testassign/action/SomeForm/refresh/refreshFor=sffwefwcwwf
       {
        "content": {
          "question1": "question1answer"
      }
      }
```

My challenge here is - I need to form the content dynamically. When first question is answered, it should go like -

```
 {
    "content": {
      "question1": "question1answer"
  }
  }
```

on change of 2nd question answer -

```
     {
        "content": {
          "question1": "question1answer"
          "question2": "question2answer"
      }
      }
```

and it goes on like this.
How do I manage the state for json body, can you please explain step by step?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this structure:

```
{
  "content": {
    "question1": "question1answer",
    "question2": "question2answer"
  }
}
```

You can find answers like this:

```
    let response = {
      "content": {
        "question1": "question1answer",
        "question2": "question2answer"
      }
    };
    let answers = Object.keys(response.content).map(item => {
      return {
         question: item,
         answer: response.content[item]
      }
    });

//"[{"question":"question1","answer":"question1answer"},{"question":"question2","answer":"question2answer"}]"
```